# Display Arabic text in android textview

Tags: android, arabic

I'm trying to develop android app where I have `html` files saved in asset folders, these files contain Arabic text like this `قُلِ اللَّهُمَّ مَالِكَ الْمُلْكِ تُؤْتِي الْمُلْكَ مَنْ تَشَاءُ وَتَنْزِعُ الْمُلْكَ مِمَّنْ تَشَاءُ` I want to set `textView` whit this text I tried Farsi class but it doesn't show it properly.
Any ideas?

Comment: *Please take a look at this : 
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25359/how-to-make-an-android-device-to-display-complex-rendering-of-indic-characters*

Comment: Which version of API are you testing against? Android supports Arabic only since [API level 17](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [android:textDirection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:textDirection) with "**anyRtl**".

- From xml: Add this line: `android:textDirection="anyRtl"` to your `TextView` tag.
- From code: `textview.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);`

PS: Since API 17+.

Comment: I have a word like "ابيات". i have an observable to set this word in textview but textview show empty string even i try to show log, in log observable value shows me accurate like "ابيات".  @Rami

Answer (score 0):

1- You need update add: android:supportsRtl="true" on manifest on application tag

```
<application
...
android:supportsRtl="true"
...>
```

2- Add textDirection in your textView

```
android:textDirection="ltr"
```