# Arabic data fetched from Microsoft SQL is not showing properly

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql

I developed a web service using java which request from the database Arabic data.
I'm using this web service in android using volley.

The problem is when i get the data and set it in text field it's show some weird symbols (Ø§ÙÙÙØ³Ù).

The collation in database is : Arabic_CI_AS

I tried many solutions but nothing works!

I would really appreciate your help

Comment: change collation type to utf8

Comment: why you need Arabic_CI_AS? utf8 will support all characters including arabic characters.

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry I can't change it to utf8 I need it to be Arabic_CI_AS. is there anyway to do that without changing it?

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry Cause it's not up to me actually I'm working with a team and they don't want to change it

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to text direction attribute for the TextView, you have to set it to "anyRtl". Not sure which version that you are working on but this is available since 17+.

This above attribute can be set in one of the following ways:

1. From XML: Add this line: `android:textDirection="anyRtl"` to your
   TextView tag.
2. From code:
   `textview.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);`

Haven't tried it though, hope this helps.
Few Links:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25359/how-to-make-an-android-device-to-display-complex-rendering-of-indic-characters
[Display Arabic text in android textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066426/display-arabic-text-in-android-textview)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextDirectionHeuristics

Comment: Thank you so much for your response , I tried it now but it didn't work.